# Add text (push) to textbox or richtextbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, chat, richtextbox, msn

I'm trying to create a chat application like msn. When i do "textBox.Text = textBox.Text+text" it updates the textbox and the text i got selected is no longer selected. In MSN you can have selected text and still recieve messages in different colors etc.. How do they do it? I figure its something like push messages, maybe they create a new textbox under another textbox? Any clues?

I hope you guys know what i'm talking about here. I just want my text to behave like MSN used to do, not update the whole textbox, just push a new message under the current message etc.

Comment: Are you using WPF ?
If so you should put a Scrollviewer over your stackpanel for example and add a new textbox each time you receive a new message.

Comment: They probably wrote all that stuff from scratch..

Comment: Its a lot more than a textbox, You should see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795738/using-richtextbox-as-a-chat-window-which-displays-text-having-text-customization

Comment: He's asking if you're using Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation

Comment: Oh, sorry.. Windows forms.

Comment: WPF : Windows Presentation Foundation. It's a presentation framework, it replaces Winforms. But If you ask the question I guess that your application is working in a browser like Chrome.

Comment: OK...you were quicker to answer :-)...So if it's Winforms I can't help I never worked with ! sorry !

Comment: Its not a webapp, its a windowsapp.. Like msn. and .exe file...

Comment: this kind of question **is hard to answer**. You should try learning/experiencing the simplest and the most basic stuff in your favorite `UI technology`. If using `Winforms`, you may want to start from `GDI+` to learn how to customize controls. If using `WPF`, you may need much less effort to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,  you just want text to stay selected when you append messages to a RichTextBox?

```
int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
int selectionLength = textBox.SelectionLength;
int carat = textBox.TextLength;

textBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
textBox.Text += newText;

//optional styling code for newly appended text
textBox.Select(carat, newText.Length);
textBox.SelectionColor = //value;
//etc.

//reapply original selection
if(selectionStart >= 0 && selectionLength > 0)
{
    textBox.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
}
```

Comment: Sort of, the code you posted does exacly that, i can imagne. But the textbox still updates, it doesnt create a new post under the current posts.

Comment: I updated the code.  Is that what you're after?  You can append more newlines to separate messages however you want.  If for some reason you don't want to keep all messages in the same textbox and use formatting to have them appear separate, then you'll need to create all new textboxes per message.  But mind your memory usage in that case.